# Is it necessary to have an approved adsense account to show ads using admob?

Tags: android, admob, adsense

Is it necessary to have an approved adsense account to use admob ?
If yes, then how to apply for it if you dont have a youtube account or a website ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a website to get an AdMob hosted AdSense account. They just want AdSense to process payments. It is required.

You have to create an Google account, apply again for AdMob and let the system create your new AdSense account.

I'm not sure if you're going to have to create another AdWords account or if you'll be given the opportunity to use an existing one.

Answer (score -1):

> Complete the following steps if you don't already have an AdSense or
>   Google Ads account associated with the Google Account you're using to
>   sign up for AdMob:
>
> Go to https://apps.admob.com.
>
> Click Sign up with your Google Account to sign up with an existing
>   Google Account or click Create a new Google Account if you want to
>   create a new account.
>
> Follow the on-screen prompts.
>
> Complete the
>   account information to create your new AdSense and Google Ads
>   accounts:

**Country or territory:**

> Select your country or territory. Your
>   selection will determine the currency we pay you in.

**Time zone:**

> Select
>   your time zone. We recommend setting the same time zone for your
>   Google Ads and AdSense accounts to ensure accuracy in reporting data.

**Google Ads billing currency:**

> Select the desired currency. This is the
>   currency you will use to pay Google if you decide to use Google Ads to
>   run paid campaigns. It can't be changed later.

-

> Check the checkbox to
>   confirm that you've read and agree to the program policies, AdSense
>   Terms & Conditions, and Google Ads Terms & Conditions.

-

> Click Create
>   AdMob account.